# Is there any easy way to draw complicated things with QPainterPath or using similar thing in PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt

I am learning right now PyQt and especially QGraphicsScene. Right now , I am trying to draw some complicated things , like for example 'human hand' , but I find QPainterPath is a little bit complicated. What can you advice ? Maybe using some openGL or some Photoshop import pictures? I am also a little bit worrying about speed, I would appreciate answers which will take in account that factor. Will put example of drawing I want to achieve. Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to implement *complicated things* then create an image as you save time.

[image]

```py
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene(backgroundBrush=QtCore.Qt.gray)
    w = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(scene)
    pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap("hand128.png")
    pixmap_item = QtWidgets.QGraphicsPixmapItem(pixmap)
    pixmap_item.setFlags(
        pixmap_item.flags()
        | QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable
        | QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable
    )
    scene.addItem(pixmap_item)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks my savior in PyQt :) Do you think it's a good practice(speed) in a long run ? Especially if you are going to make something like buttons out of it in future? Since I will also need clicked state and etc. I thought also about pictures , but if I will have 50 buttons in one UI , it will be already100 pics.

Comment: @Vlad Is that you have to decide between memory or speed, if it is quick, my option is the right one since the task of "creating the image" would not be done but in counterpart you would have to load 100 images in ram, but if you want to save memory you would have to make a painting online which involves a time of "creation of the image", but for 100 images I do not see that there is a difference. In the end the last option depends on the tests you do.